# Pass value to the previous webpage in php

Tags: php, cookies

I want to know how I can pass value by cookie from one page to the pervious one ,

This is my code

Readcookie.php

```
<?php 
foreach($_COOKIE as $key => $value)
    {echo("<p>$key: $value</p>");
    $name=($_COOKIE['name']);

    }

     print('<a href="coockie.php?name:"'.$name'>Go to Home</a>');
    ?>
```

Cookie.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <?php  
 $name=$_GET['name'];
 echo'Hello'.$name;
 ?>
<form method="post" action="setcookie.php">
<label>Name<input type="text" name="name"></label>
<label>Age<input type="number" name="age"></label> 
<input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>

</html>
```

setcookie.php

```
<?php 

setcookie("name" , $_POST['name'] , time()+60*60*24*1);
setcookie("Age" , $_POST['age'] , time()+60*60*24*1);


?>

<p> To read cookie click </p> 

<a href="readcookie.php">Here</a>
```

What I want when I go back from readingcookie.php page to Coockie.php page , 
I found Welcome username ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, You have a typo: `?name:"'.$name'` should be: `?name="'.$name'`

In your script line:

```
     print('<a href="coockie.php?name:"'.$name'>Go to Home</a>');
```

should be:

```
     print('<a href="coockie.php?name="'.$name'>Go to Home</a>');
```

Second, why aren't you using `$_COOKIE['name']` to get the name in Cookie.php (instead of: `$_GET['name']`, in your example?)
You can use it like this 9(change in: Cookie.php) :

```
<?php 
$name = ( isset($_COOKIE['name']) ) ? $_COOKIE['name'] : "guest" ;  
echo'Hello'.$name;
?>
```